# How to get the thread used by a python function?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying a sample code for multithreading in python, which was found in [this doc page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

The actual code is the following:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

I would like the `load_url` function to print out the id of the thread it is currently using so I can monitor if multithreading is actually working. Of course if you have better ways to achieve this same goal, please let me know.

Thanks

**Edit**

I think I just bumped into the answer, this seems to work

```
# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
import threading
def load_url(url, timeout):
    print('Using thread {}, looking for url {}'.format(threading.get_ident(), url))
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()
```

any feedback on preferred methods are however welcome.

Comment: [`aiohttp`](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/) may be interesting for you...

Comment: ``threading.get_ident`` is exactly what you are asking for.